# HTML Template parsing in web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I am trying to solve this `web2py` problem and I think I have some basic misunderstanding of what's going on.

Say I have a shop, and I want to have in my `index.html` many boxes with products. I want each such box to be parsed from a template.

What I tried to do to have the following architecture. In the controller I have

```
def index():
   products = db().select(db.products.ALL)
   return dict(products=products)
```

in `index.html`:

```
{{for i in range(0,len(products)):}}
  {{ context=dict(product=products[i])  }}
  {{ =response.render('template.html', context)}}
{{pass}}
```

and in `template.html` I have something like

```
<div id=...> <h1> {{=product.price}} </h1>...
```

The problem is that the result is read **literaly**. That is, when browse the `index.html` I see html tags:

[image]

I suspect that my whole approach is wrong. How should one do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{{for product in products:}}
  {{=XML(response.render('template.html', product.as_dict()))}}
{{pass}}
```

In template.html:

```
<div id=...> <h1> {{=price}} </h1>...
```

`response.render()` returns a string, and all strings are escaped in templates. To prevent the escaping, you must wrap the string in `XML()`.

The above also includes a couple of simplifications. In the `for` loop, you can just iterate directly over the rows in `products`, and you can then convert a single product row to a dict and pass that dict as the context to template.html (so you can just refer to `price` rather than `product.price`).

Note, if you don't need to use template.html elsewhere, you might as well just move its contents directly into the `for` loop within index.html.